# Checkbox to toggle admin in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a parent table in which there is admin and superadmin field. Superadmin can assign other parents as admin or superadmin. I want a checkbox in front of list of parents showing that if any checkbox is checked shows that the particular parent is admin or superadmin and if nothing is checked shows that the particular parent is neither an admin nor  superadmin.How can a superadmin assign or remove any that particular parent as admin or superadmin by just unchecking the checked box. please help

[image: sample image of my requirement]

Update

```
<td><%= check_box_tag 'admin', true, parent.admin, :onclick => 'this.form.submit()'  %></td>
<td><%= check_box_tag 'superadmin', true, parent.superadmin, :onclick => 'this.form.submit()'  %></td>
```

how can I uncheck the admin or superadmin and that parent is removed as admin or superadmin respectively.

Update
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share where you are getting stuck?

Comment: @Sinstein . I am not able to figure out how to check or uncheck the admin and superadmin fields so that the boolean for these fields changes in the database.

Comment: @Sinstein please check the update above. how can i uncheck to remove or check to assign so that the boolean for admin or superadmin changes in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= form_tag update_status_path, :method => 'patch' do %>
 <tbody>
  <% @parents.each do |parent| %>
   <tr> 
    <td><%= link_to parent.email,parent_path(parent) %></td>
     <td><%= check_box_tag "parents[#{parent.id}][admin]", true, parent.admin, class: 'status', data: {id: parent.id, type: 'admin'} %></td>
     <td><%= check_box_tag "parents[#{parent.id}][superadmin]", true, parent.superadmin, class: 'status', data: {id: parent.id, type: 'superadmin'} %></td>
   </tr>
  <% end %>
 </tbody>
```

parents_controller.rb

```
def manage_users
    @parents = Parent.search(params[:search]).order(params[:sort]).admins
    @parents_to_update = []
end
```

routes.rb

```
get 'main-admin/manage-users', to: 'parents#manage_users'
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach can be like this:

- Change the `check_box` fields to

  ```
  <%= check_box_tag 'admin', true,  parent.admin, class: 'status', data: {id: parent.id, type: 'admin'} %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'superadmin', true, parent.superadmin, class: 'status', data {id: parent.id, type: 'superadmin' }%>
  ```
- Add this javascript

  ```
  $(".status").on('change', function(){
      var $this = $(this) 
      var parent_id = $this.data('id'); 
      $.ajax({
        url: 'status/parent/' + parent_id,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {type: $this.data('type'), value: this.checked }
      });
    });
  ```
- Add this at `ParentsController`

  ```
  def change_status
     @parent = Parent.find(params[:id])

     if @parent.update_attributes(params[:type] => params[:value])
        redirect_to parents_path
     end
  end
  ```
- And this to the `routes.rb` file

  ```
  post 'status/parent/:id' => 'parents#change_status'
  ```

In the controller the `:id` from the path ends up in `params[:id]`. The data from the ajax request also ends up in the params hash, hence `params[:type]` and `params[:value]`.